# How can I pass a custom request header from WebSEAL to IBM HTTP Server?

Tags: httpserver, request-headers, ibmhttpserver, webseal

I have discovered no way to pass custom REQUEST headers from WebSEAL to IBM HTTP Server.

I can do this on Bluecoat reverse proxies and also Nginx, but I am trying to do this with WebSEAL.

Currently running both IBM Tivoli Access Manager/WebSEAL version 6.x and IBM Security Access Manager/WebSEAL version 7.x.

Please note, I am specifying REQUEST headers, and not custom RESPONSE headers.

Answer (score 1):

It kinda depends on where the data for the header originates from. There is builtin support for specifying attributes from user's LDAP entry in the headers. You can read about it in the [scattered](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_7.0.0/com.ibm.isam.doc_70/ameb_authc_guide/concept/con_attr_entl_serv_config.html) throughout [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_7.0.0.1/com.ibm.isam.doc_80/ameb_webplugin_guide/task/tsk_add_reg_ext_attri_http.html).
Any custom (constant, or computed) values must be present in the credential attributes, and this could involve coding custom C library for the [Credential attributes entitlement service](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_7.0.0/com.ibm.isam.doc_70/ameb_authc_guide/concept/con_crdl_attr_entl_serv.html).

Comment: The headers would be injected by WebSEAL and passed along to IHS.  This would be a global static header added to all requests and not specific to particular users or dynamic in any way.  I know that Bluecoat can add X-headers and such.  I'm just looking for an easy way to do this with WebSEAL, and it seems like it should be extremely simple, but the answer keeps eluding me.